# Null Object error when trying to set up navigation view listener

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to setup a click listener in my menu which inside of a navigation view inside a fragment- I want to set the listener inside of my fragment as well

I am getting the error

```
"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference"
```

When I try to run this code

```
public class FragmentNavigationDrawer extends Fragment implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
}
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue? thanks

Comment: your activity context is null

Comment: have you debug the code ?

Comment: no im new to android- could you tell me how to fix this is link to a guide?

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi "your activity context is null" - How did you get that from the given error message?

Comment: @Bruce are you aware about debugging the code. If yes then please debug your code. and let me know value of getACtivity, navigationView and this instance

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi sorry not really, all i know is that the line navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this) is causing it to crash

Comment: try below code and let me know if there is an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. Replace getACtivity with getView()

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
}

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

Comment: I actually found out that this View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) view.findViewById(R.id.nav_view); code makes the error go away, thanks though

Answer (score 4):

Check these two lines in your `onCreateView`:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

You are getting `NullPointerException` because `navigationView` object is null. Check whether you are providing a valid id for your `NavigationView`. Check your XML part whether id for `NavigationView` is same as `nav_view` or different.

Answer (score 1):

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

this line is your problem you just need to erase it because you already implements it in your class. So erase this line and call the @Override Method

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {}
```

This will normaly work great.